# Accessing nested data from MongoDB in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have deeply nested JSON objects that I'm saving in MongoDB. Saving them is done successfully, but the problem is I cannot access the whole object. How can I access (or avoid) this [Object] part? This is how the saved data looks on the console when I get it from the db.

```
{
  json: {
    id: '0',
    name: null,
    parentId: null,
    folderType: 'chatCannedMessages',
    folders: [ [Object] ],
    items: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("6340adf1b0258d258fe3e4d3"),
  __v: 0
}
```

I am calling mongoose's find() on the schema to get the data.
And this is how my schema looks like, as before I tried saving it with complex references, but it didnt work so I went with this simple approach:

```
const  MessageModel = new Schema({
  json: Object,
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation $unwind first and then $project to get desired output.

```
data.aggregate([
    {
     $unwind:{path:'document_key'}
    {
    $project:{
    "Key1":1;
    "Key2":0;    
       }
      }
    }
    ]);
```

1 is for showing the field and 0 is for not.
replace key according to your need

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I'm a newbie to MongoDB so I can't really understand what's going on here